# Functions in epic are firing out of order and I can't understand why

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, redux-observable

*SOLVED
The problem was in how I was creating and responding to the observable created by the firebase callback.
I also had way too much stuff going on inside my firebase callbacks. 
I ended up splitting it up a bit more, using the firebase promise structure: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html
and creating an Observable.fromPromise for the firebase callback within what is now called firebaseAPI.checkForUser.
*

Working epic:

```
export const contactFormFirebaseSubmitEpic = (action$) =>
action$.ofType(START_CONTACT_FORM_FIREBASE_SUBMIT)
  .flatMap((firebaseSubmitAction) => {
   const values = firebaseSubmitAction.values;
   const formattedEmail = firebaseAPI.getFormattedEmail(values);
   const contactsRef = firebaseAPI.getContactsRef(formattedEmail);
    return firebaseAPI.checkForUser(values, formattedEmail, contactsRef);
 })
  .flatMap((data) => concat(
        of(firebaseAPI.recordUserAndUpdateDetails(data))
      ))
  .flatMap((data) => concat(
     of(firebaseAPI.setQuoteData(data))
    ))
  .switchMap((x) => merge(
      of(stopLoading()),
      of(contactFormFirebaseSuccess())
    ));
```

// original question

Ok so, what I'm trying to achieve is to perform the first action (firebaseAPI.checkUserAndUpdate), then the next, then when both of them are done essentially discard what's there and send out two actions (contactFormFirebaseSuccess and stopLoading).

This all works fine except for one weird thing, the setQuoteData function always runs before the checkUser function. Does anyone know why this might be?

Also if there's a better way to lay this out I'd be very open to suggestions! Cheers. Also I've taken out quite a few variables and things that would make it even more complicated. Basically I just wanted to show that in each case I'm returning an observable from 'doing something with firebase'. But I don't think that's the problem as I have console logs in each of the firebase functions and the setQuoteData one just fires first and then executes the firebase stuff then when it's done the checkUserAndUpdate one runs.

```
export const contactFormFirebaseSubmitEpic = action$ =>
action$.ofType(START_CONTACT_FORM_FIREBASE_SUBMIT)
.flatMap((firebaseSubmitAction) => {
  const values = firebaseSubmitAction.values;
  return merge(
    firebaseAPI.checkUserAndUpdate(values),
    firebaseAPI.setQuoteData(values),
  )
  .takeLast(1)
  .mergeMap((x) => {
    return merge(
        of(contactFormFirebaseSuccess()),
        of(stopLoading()),
      );
  });
});


const firebaseAPI = {

  checkUserAndUpdate: (values) => {
   const checkUserAndUpdateDetails = firebaseRef.once('value', snapshot => {
     const databaseValue = snapshot.val();
     checkUserExistsAndUpdateDetails(databaseValue, values);
    });
   return Observable.from(checkUserAndUpdateDetails);
  },

  setQuoteData: (value) => {
    const setQuote = setQuoteData(values);
    return Observable.from(setQuote);
    },
};

const stopLoading = () => ({ type: STOP_BUTTON_LOADING });
const contactFormFirebaseSuccess = () => ({ type: SUCCESS });

 checkUserAndUpdate: (values, contactsRef) => {
    const checkUser$ = Observable.from(contactsRef.once('value').then( 
    snapshot => {
    const databaseValue = snapshot.val();
    checkUserExistsAndUpdateDetails(
      values,
      databaseValue,
      contactsRef,);
  })
);
     return checkUser$;
 },

const checkUserExistsAndUpdateDetails = (
  values,
  databaseValue,
  contactsRef,
) => {
 if (databaseValue) { console.log('user exists'); }
  else {
     console.log('new user, writing to database');
     contactsRef.set({
      name: values.name,
      email: values.email,
      phone: values.phone,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: checkUserAndUpdateDetails  is not synchronous (it takes callback) whereas setQuoteData *is* synchronous. So it will send it's value first, it doesn't need callback to finish

Comment: Hi but sorry the full functions weren't included but setQuoteData is asynchronous? But I'd say it potentially completes the quickest, would that matter? I thought one wasn't supposed to start until the last completed?

Comment: But I do see your point in that the checkUser... function is explicitly in a callback via firebase... The thing is if I do something like flatMap(do first function).flatMap(do second function) that does them in the correct order, but how would I pass a source value into the second function in that instance? i.e not the value that gets returned from the first flatMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `merge` does not maintain the order of the streams that you subscribe to, it simply emits events from any of the source streams regardless of what order they emit.

If you need to maintain order you should use `concat` instead of `merge`

i.e.

```
  const values = firebaseSubmitAction.values;
  return concat(
    firebaseAPI.checkUserAndUpdate(values),
    firebaseAPI.setQuoteData(values),
  )
```

Side note, I don't know why you are using the `of` operator there, you already have Observables returned from your API so you can just pass those to `merge` or `concat` in this case.

Comment: Great that makes a lot of sense. I'll give that a try cheers!

Comment: actually no, If the user doesn't exist and it has to go into the firebase callback it still comes in the wrong order. I also changed mergeMap to concatMap as well as merge to concat inside that

Comment: Aah something is wrong with how my observables and firebase are setup. Basically the functions are running in the right order, but 'return Observable.from(checkUserAndUpdateDetails);' is returning an observable before the callback handler fires anything... I think this might be more of a firebase issue than RXJS, i.e how to you set it up so you only return a promise once an event fires

Comment: Your code is somewhat confusing to me, you seem to be recursively calling your methods? from within the callbacks?

Comment: Sorry I've added the structure of the checkUser function in my code above ^^

Comment: Oh sorry I see what you mean, yeah I am because I can't actually check against the value in the database until I've received something back to check (in the callback), but I think the problem is I'm getting an observable back before the callback fires. Because it executes like this:
1) checkUser function runs
2) setQuoteData function runs
3) Callback inside checkUser fires